# How to create a nested for loop using dataframe and vector as 2 sets of values?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, nested-loops, data-manipulation

Here I have 6 columns with 3 values in each so 3 rows

```
 ob1 <- rep(1,3)
 ob2 <- rep(2,3)
 ob3 <-rep(3,3)
 ob4 <- rep(4,3)
 ob5 <- rep(5,3)
 ob6 <- rep(6,3)

 df <- data.frame(ob1,ob2,ob3,ob4,ob5,ob6)

 df
  ob1 ob2 ob3 ob4 ob5 ob6
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   2   1   2   3   4   5   6
   3   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

This value vector will always have the  length equal to # of rows in DF

```
  value <- c(1.9,2.3,4.5)
```

I want to be able to loop through DF rows and index of value (i and j) so I don't have to manually create test multiple times (in this example, for the 3 rows)

`df[1,]` specifies the row and `value[1]` is the first element in vector so they match in length

```
 test <- sum((df[1,]-value[1])**2) / 6
 test
 5.4766
```

There should be 3 test values because 3 rows, how do I loop?

Comment: É só `rowSums(df - value)`.

Comment: I will change the formula above, but the formula will be more complicated then a simple sum

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the formula to the rowSums and did some manipulation and it is what I needed. Thank you for  informing me about this function!

Comment: OK, but I have just realized I had posted my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517113/how-to-create-a-nested-for-loop-using-dataframe-and-vector-as-2-sets-of-values?noredirect=1#comment122873782_69517113) in Portuguese (I'm simultaneously on pt.SO) . It's only `rowSums(df - value)` or `rowSums((df - value)**2)/6`. This works because in R vectors are *column* vectors and the formula subtracts `value` from the 1st col, then from the 2nd col, etc. And you say that `length(value)` is always equal to `nrow(df)` so it should always work.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did on my own. Thank you for that, I always forget the base functions in R are very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Idea from [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517113/how-to-create-a-nested-for-loop-using-dataframe-and-vector-as-2-sets-of-values#comment122873782_69517113) You could do:

```
rowMeans((df - value)^2)
[1] 5.476667 4.356667 3.916667
```

Comment: Yep I did that on my own after Rui mentioned the rowMeans function. Thanks!